# EDI to XML Conversion

Tags: java, xml, edi

I'm searching for a free EDI to XML converter in Java.

I need to convert EDI 940 to xml and convert XML to EDI 945.  The catch is that this will be used for a commercial project, I've found some projects on sourceforge but they are under GNU General Public License which if I read it correctly means I would need to pay to use it for a commercial project.  Any links are appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

GPL allows you to sell copies of your appliaction but you have to give access to your source code and anyone that purchased a copy is free to give the software away for free. Depending on your business this might not really be a problem. Imho "closed source" for commercial projects is overrated, there are several examples of companies that do well with open source projects.

Another point is how you include the GPL software in your project. If you do not link to the software directly you also do not need to make your software GPL (at least this is my understanding; you would need to verify this properly once you know how to use the GPL software).

Maybe more problematic is if you have to use other libraries that are not GPL compatible, system libraries on the other hand are not really a problem (so called "system library exception").

More information on GPL is [here](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you **distribute** your application to users, then the GPL would require you also make available your source.